# Issue with Folder names returned by FindNextFile

Tags: c++, winapi, filenames

I have a rather awkward problem with `FindNextFile`. I've attached the relevant code block below.

The code works perfectly in 99% of cases. The issue is when a folder name starts with a float value. I have a folder containing `"0.0W"` , `"1.0W"` , `"3.9W"`, `"4.1W"` and `"7.0W"`. Those are the names of the folders on the drive. when I try to grab the string from the returned `WIN32_FIND_DATA` structure. I grab the parameter `lcFindData.cFileName` which is a wide character string and the contents are incorrect.

i.e.

- `"0.0W"` returns as `"0W"`
- `"1.0W"` returns as `"1W"`
- `"3.9W"` returns as `"3.9W"`
- `"4.1W"` returns as `"4.1W"`
- `"7.0W"` returns as `"7.0W"`

As far as I can see it is converting the floats into floats then converting them back into strings making them inaccurate. Except `7.0W` which it seems happy about...

```
void nsDialogFunctions::cFileList::ListFolders(string lsPath,uint32 liMax)
{   
    //Empty List
    SetItems(0);
    lsPath+="/*";
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA lcFindData;
    //Find First Folder (".")
    hFind = FindFirstFile(nsConversionFunctions::ConvertToWString(lsPath).c_str(),&lcFindData);
    DWORD dwError=0;
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind) 
    {
       return;
    } 
    // Fins Second Folder ("..")
    FindNextFile(hFind, &lcFindData);
    //Find first valid folder
    FindNextFile(hFind, &lcFindData);
    // List all the files in the directory with some info about them.
    do
    {
        if ((lcFindData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
        {
            string *lcTemp=new string;
            //lcFindData.cFileName is sometimes wrong here. 
            //It is wrong before entering ConvertWString
            lcTemp[0]=nsConversionFunctions::ConvertWString(lcFindData.cFileName);
            Add(lcTemp);
        }
    }
    while (FindNextFile(hFind, &lcFindData) != 0 && (!liMax || Items()<liMax));
    FindClose(hFind);
    return;
};
```

Have I done something wrong with `hFind`?

Is there a setting I can change to remove this behaviour?

Is there another access point for getting the returned string?

Comment: 1. What does `ConvertWString` do?
2. Why are you doing this `lcTemp[0]=nsConversionFunctions::ConvertWString(lcFindData.cFileName);`?

Comment: ConvertWString Will convert a Wide character string or wchar * to a char string. Due to various other libraries and functionality used we use std::string<char> as our default text container

Comment: I believe the problem is somewhere in `nsConversionFunctions::ConvertWString`. `FindNextFile` does not do any conversions itself, it would return filename "as is". It would be much easier to help, if you can provide [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: There is no `std::string<char>`. You probably mean `std::basic_string<char>`. You should show the content of `ConvertWString`.

Answer (score 1):

`FindFirstFile`, `FindNextFile` return the correct names for the file system objects. Your code in `ConvertWString` then modifies those names to the values that you see.

I'm not a very big fan of your decision to use 8 bit text, unless of course that text is UTF-8 encoded. If your text is ANSI encoded then there's nothing to be gained from using the wide APIs. You would be better served calling `FindFirstFileA`, `FindNextFileA` etc. and letting the system perform the text conversion. For sure it will get it right!